# Hiding error message for one validator type but not another MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to have a ValidationMessageFor helper only display the error message for one of the field's validators. For example if I had a field in my model like this:

```
[Required]
[Remote("SymbolUnique", "RemoteValidation", ErrorMessage = "A document already exists in the database for the entered symbol")]
public string Symbol { get; set; }
```

I wouldn't want to show the message for required, being happy with just the visual indication of the textbox being highlighted, but show the message for the remote validator. If I set the ErrorMessage parameter of the required attribute to an empty string I get an error for setting both the ErrorMessage and ErrorMessageResourceName as the framework starts being too clever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's ugly but this will work

```
public class CustomeRequired : RequiredAttribute
{
    public CustomeRequired()
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I had considered a custom required validator but was hoping there was a more elegant solution to what is really a configuration rather than implementation problem. However in lieu of any other suggestions its accepted!